# How do I specify that a project depends on another project?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I have a couple projects: one with the code for a REST API client and another one for a **scraper** . Both of them have been built using the conventions of [The Hitchhicker's Guide to Python](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/), so they have their own requirements.txt, setup.py, etc.

Now, the **scraper** project depends on the Client project. How do I specify that dependency? Should I place it on the requirements.txt? In the setup.py as install_requires or what? I think, in both cases, I would be specifying a third party library, which is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personnaly I add them in setup.py

```
setup(
    ...
    install_requires=[my_package>=1.0.42, ...]
    ...
)
```

Comment: But that implies pip will look for your package in PyPI, right? So that dependency will fail.

Comment: You can deploy your sub project with python setup.py develop to add it in your virtualenv with symbolic links

Comment: That sounds like the best approach. Thanks.